# How to get unique entries in a slice of maps golang

Tags: go

How to get unique entries from below JSON in Go. In the output I should get unique key-value pairs.Here in the input there are 2 same keys *type* and different values for them. So in the output I should get one key as *type* and combined values for them. And If there are duplicate key-value pairs one pair needs to be removed.
This is my input

```
{
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "name",
            "values": [
                "name"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Type",
            "values": [
                "type1",
                "type2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Id",
            "values": [
                "id"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Type",
            "values": [
                "type3",
                "type4"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And output should look like this

```
{
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "name",
            "values": [
                "name"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Type",
            "values": [
                "type1",
                "type2",
                "type3",
                "type4"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Id",
            "values": [
                "id"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the code I tried to add uniqueness to the name field. But I need values field uniqueness as well

```
    var res []models.Attributes
    var attributes []models.Attributes
    keys := make(map[string]bool)

    for _, item := range attributes {
            if _, value := keys[item.Name]; !value {
                keys[item.Name] = true
                res = append(res, item)
            }
        }
        return res
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please update the Q with the code you have

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  Use a map of maps where the outer map represents an attribute and the keys of the inner map are the unique values for that attribute:

```
m := make(map[string]map[string]bool)
```

Loop through the data creating maps as needed:

```
for _, item := range attributes {
    values := m[item.Name]
    if values == nil {
        values = make(map[string]true)
        m[item.Name] = values
    }
    for _, value := range item.Values {
        values[value] = true
    }
}
```

Recreate the slice of attributes from the map:

```
attributes = attributes[:0] // overwrite the attributes
for name, values := range m {
    attribute := Attribute{Name: name}
    for value := range values {
        attribute.Values = append(attribute.Values, value)
    }
    attributes = append(attributes, attribute)
}
```

View the code in action on the [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/jm-S98FbiYR).